# htaccess: RewriteRule not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to clean my url from this:

https://www.sobarroso.pt/stand-carros-usados/?brand=2&model=&category=&fuel=&kms=&price=

into this:

https://www.sobarroso.pt/stand-carros-usados/alfa-romeo

but when i creat the rule in .htaccess it just doesn´t work.
Here it´s a snippet of my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

And the code i was trying to add was this:

```
RewriteRule ^stand-carros-usados/alfa-romeo$ /stand-carros-usados/?brand=2&model=&category=&fuel=&kms=&price= [L]
```

What am i doing wrong? I'm just starting to play with .htaccess so i need you help guys.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

hey guys, i keep playing with the codes and feel im almost there. this time i used this one

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/stand-carros-usados [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^brand=(.*)&model=(.*)&category=(.*)&fuel=(.*)&kms=(.*)&price=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.sobarroso.pt/stand-carros-usados/alfa-romeo? [L]
```

and it worked. The url is clean but gives me a 404 page. Do you know why?

Comment: Where were you adding your rule? Don't put a _snippet_, instead post the whole file.

Comment: You need to use `RewriteCond` with `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable to match query strings